Find the number of SIMD lines in comptime in Rust
I wrote the following simd-friendly code for dot product:
pub fn scalar_product_simd<T>(a: &[T], b: &[T]) -> T
where
    T: Mul<Output = T> + Sum + Copy + Add<Output = T>,
{
    const CHUNK_SIZE: usize = 4;
    assert!(a.len() >= CHUNK_SIZE && b.len() >= CHUNK_SIZE && a.len() == b.len());

    let mut i = 0;
    let mut acc = a
        .chunks_exact(CHUNK_SIZE)
        .zip(b.chunks_exact(CHUNK_SIZE))
        .map(|(aa, bb)| {
            i += CHUNK_SIZE;
            aa.iter().zip(bb).map(|(&x, &y)| x * y).sum()
        })
        .sum();

    // handle remaining elements
    acc = acc + scalar_product(&a[i..], &b[i..]);
    acc
}

How can I set the CHUNK_SIZE value in accordance with the compilation parameters and the size of the T type. For example, for T:f64 and AVX2 CHUNK_SIZE will be equal to 4 ?
Perhaps there is a correct way to rewrite this code using std::simd ?

The only way I know is to have cfg!(target_feature = "SIMD_FEATURE") with manual numbers.

I don't think I fully understand your question, but if you want to have different values of constant CHUNK_SIZE depending on the type of T, and there is a finite number of Ts you want to support, you could crate a helper trait.
trait SimdHelper {
    const CHUNK_SIZE: usize;
}

impl SimdHelper for f64 {
    const CHUNK_SIZE: usize = 4;
}

pub fn scalar_product_simd<T>(a: &[T], b: &[T]) -> T
where
    T: Mul<Output = T> + Sum + Copy + Add<Output = T>,
    T: SimdHelper,
{
    const CHUNK_SIZE: usize = <T as SimdHelper>::CHUNK_SIZE;

    ...
}

